# Actionscript 3 with single constructor argument?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

let's say I have a class:

```
public class SomeClass{
    var name:String;
    public function SomeClass(n){
        name = n;
    }
}
```

If I do `var s:SomeClass = SomeClass("test");`, it tries to convert a string to `SomeClass`. How do I prevent it from doing that?

Sorry I'm new to AS3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the `new` operator:

`var s:SomeClass = new SomeClass('test');`

---

Unless you use the `new` operator, there really isn't a good way to create a Class member in ActionScript. There are some noteable exceptions, however. Array, XML, XMLList, int, uint, Number, String, and Object should almost never use their constructors.

```
//To get a new array
var a:Array = [/*initial values*/];
// a new Object
var o:Object = {};
```

In AS, use of the class's name as function is actually "Cast this to the class". You can also do this through the `as` operator. The difference is that `as` will return null on failure the other means will throw an error:

```
// I NEED this to be a Foo, so I will force the matter.
var foo:Foo = Foo(otherVariable);

// It would be nice to have this as a Foo, but if it is null, whatever:
var foo:Foo = otherVariable as Foo.
```

Comment: Wow. Fail. I'm more used to python and C++'s without new (for non pointer to object)

Comment: @ultimatebuster As someone more used to C++ influenced languages, Python's lack of the `new` keyword is... troubling at times. It is far more Mathematically correct, (and I find Py3k to be one of the best languages ever), but it is a major paradigm shift.

Comment: I like Py2. Lacking of new is not a big issue. I find that converting 1 object to another seems somewhat illogical and should be avoided anyway. Since Python is all about ducttyping, the decision to leave `new` out is, in my opinion, a good thing.

Comment: @ultimatebuster I like Py3k because it has a couple features which makes it more clearly tied to mathematics. Duck Typing does not work very well in ActionScript -- you are best off strong typing wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen it try to auto-convert data types like you are saying it does.
But in anycase you are not type casting your parameter and you are not declaring a return type.
Being a constructor it needs to return void.
You are also not declaring the scope of the variable name/
Also you are not declaring the package

```
package{
  public class SomeClass{
      public var name:String;
      public function SomeClass(n:String):void{
          this.name = n;
      }
  }
}
```